# What is the best way to store special character in database?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a string that will contain special character.

```
for example
EC-1CF08540B7799143A
```

Whenever I am trying to store it into database it will save it as

```
EC%2d1CF08540B7799143A
```

What will be the best way to store strings with special characters in `mySQL` and retrieve the original form using PHP?

Comment: Use utf8 encoding to store these values.

Comment: What encoding converts a hyphen to %2d?

Comment: if you got your answer then please mark as complete question..

Answer (score 1):

Check what encoding the database is using, then make sure that the `meta` tag in your HTML file is also using the same encoding type.

To find out the encoding of your table, use

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable;
```

This will output the create statement for the table, including the encoding (`CHARSET`).

In your HTML head, you should have a line such as

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Make sure that the CHARSET in your SQL output matches this or vice-versa.

Ideally, they will both be using UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Set column Collation as "urf_general_ci" to that particular column ans try.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
<?php
$sting = $_REQUEST['string'];
$new_string = str_replace("%2d", "-", $string);
?>
```

Now save this ***$new_sting*** into database.

Comment: You probably wanted `$string` as the first variable, `$sting` sounds tasty though.

Comment: That assumes that the only character that needs converting is a hyphen, which I wouldn't even regard as a special character. If you start manually converting encoding errors then you're on your way to a world of (programming) pain.